# Native IPv6 on Debian Router

Tags: linux, debian, router, ipv6, dnsmasq

After my old Tomato USB router died I started using an old netbook with Debian Wheezy installed as my home router.

I have two WLAN interfaces and one LAN interface. wlan0 has internet access and wlan1 and eth0 are bridged for my local network. Recently my ISP got native IPv6 and wlan0 was assigned a /64 without issue, I got everything working nicely with IPv4 NAT.

My question is how I can allow devices on my LAN (br0) to get assigned IPv6 addresses from my /64 so I can stop using miredo for IPv6 connectivity. I use DNSMASQ for DHCP and would like to use it for IPv6 if possible.

I already tried the following in my /etc/dnsmasq.conf to no avail

```
dhcp-range=::f,constructor:wlan0,ra-names,1d
enable-ra
```

along with the following

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
syscll -w net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra=2
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting up a `radvd` server on your linux host.  It should be happy announcing your /64 on the LAN interfaces.  The configuration file is quite simple.  Normally, you will have an almost empty IPv6 /64 for your uplink and at least one more /64 for your internal network.

Secure your network with `ip6tables`.   There are a number of icmp6 types that are required for the network to work.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am trying radvd, is there anyway to get the prefix from an existing interface instead of hardcoding it in the config?